# PHP math strange behavior

Tags: php

I have phantom bug in my code. It appears in one case from 10 attempts. When I try to debug it I found this strange behavior:

```
$a = floor(1385968017.8665 * 10000); // or (int) (1385968017.8665 * 10000)
// here $a equals to 13859680178664
$b = (1385968017.8665 * 10000);
// here $b equals to 13859680178665
```

I have such PHP version/configuration:

```
PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep  4 2013 20:00:51) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2013, by Derick Rethans
```

**UPDATE:**
I know about floating operations precesion. Same code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::fixed << (1385968017.8665 * 10000) << std::endl;
    std::cout << (unsigned long long) (1385968017.8665 * 10000) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

gives me next output:

```
13859680178664.998047
13859680178664
```

And it was I expected from it. But why my PHP code shows that (1385968017.8665 * 10000) is precise equals to 13859680178665?

**UPDATE 2:**
As user @core1024 mentioned in comments, PHP possible is rounding result of calculation (1385968017.8665 * 10000). If try `php -r 'printf("%f\n",1385968017.8665 * 10000);'` result will be somewhere about `13859680178664.998047`. Who can explain when and why PHP do this?

Comment: I get 13859680178700 in both cases... Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) PHP/5.2.6

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Exactly, but why (1385968017.8665 * 10000) is equals to 13859680178665 in my case?

Comment: PHP Is rounding it either case. Try `php -r 'printf("%f\n",1385968017.8665 * 10000);'`

Comment: Check my answer, and especially follow thru the link (Which leads to a blog by Jon Skeet). Hopefully you'll be enlightened as to why the values output like that.

Comment: @core1024 Can you explain me when PHP rounds it? And why? I a little familiar with zend engine and I very interesting within it!

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea why. If I knew it I would post it as an answer here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found explanation for this problem. My php.ini precision setting is equal to 14. If I increase precision setting by one, this stragne behavior not represented:

```
$a = floor(1385968017.8665 * 10000); // or (int) (1385968017.8665 * 10000)
// here $a equals to 1385968017866(!)5
```

Answer (score 2):

It runs as expected.

You used the `FLOOR()` function in the first statement, which **ROUNDS DOWN** a value to the nearest integer.

Check [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_math_floor.asp) for more info on that.

As to why it rounds down like that, it's because your value `1385968017.8665` isn't **exactly** that. Jon Skeet explains that [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx) ..along with Tony the Pony.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of 1385968017.8665 is an infinite double in binary,
and (literal 1385968017.8665) ~= (1385968017.8664998 in computer).

Is round(1385968017.8665 * 10000) what you need?

Comment: Excactly in this case round gives me correct result. But I always want to retrive nearest integer value less or equals to "ideal division result" without floating operations magic. Using round don't save me from phantom bug in my code.